# Java: Unexpected size issues with SortedMap

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, sortedmap

This code:

```
intersectionMap.size() + "" + intersectionMap.isEmpty()
```

Returns

```
9true
```

Any thoughts? I cant think of any reason this would occur.. Im using the SortedMap type provided by Java as seen here [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) (group decision, I'm not familiar with the type).

`intersectionMap` is obtained from a group of objects that are the result of parsing some map data (xml).

Maybe some of the gurus know whats happening?

Comment: Whats the actual implementation being used? Please include the full class name in your question.

Comment: Where is `intersectionMap` coming from?  Its name sounds like it's a custom view.

Comment: Some typo perhaps? Is this code copy paste or did you type it?

Comment: Me and my team made the program so far. But that code sample / output is direct copy paste. So with no concurrent modification, I dont understand the contradiction. They're spelt the same etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SortedMap is an interface. We need to know the actual implementation being used.
It's possible that you don't create the implementation yourself, then you have to see it in debug or read library's documentation.

In my project I can see about 40 different implementations of SortedMap interface, so we hardly can guess which one is used in your application.

If inherited from AbstractMap and both methods are not overridden, it's pretty much guaranteed to work properly. That's the original implementation:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
return size() == 0;
}
```